# MeshBasicMaterial Three.js brightness

Tags: javascript, html, colors, three.js, rgb

I am currently using a MeshBasicMaterial in threejs to be lights. There is a fake point light inside of each one.
I have a variable called `color`. It is `rgb(random value, random value, random value)`. I want the MeshBasicMaterial to be brighter, currently. Is there any way to do this? I am open to switching to another material if I need to.

Comment: [MeshBasicMaterial is not affected by lights.](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=meshbasicmaterial#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial)

Comment: It would be great if you could accept and upvote my answer :)

Comment: yeah but that sorta feels passive aggressive lol

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mean for it to sound that way xD

Comment: That's fine. Thank you, nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated by @PhilN:

> MeshBasicMaterial is not affected by lights.

I would recommend to changing to `MeshLambertMaterial` or `MeshPhongMaterial` instead, which will both become brighter/darker depending on the values of your light source(s).